# Erro na passagem de uma estrutura por referencia C

Tags: c

Nesse exercício é necessária a troca somente dos caracteres a por b, ou seja saída do printf deve ser assim 
{B, 1.5, 2.7}
{A, 3.9, 4.2}

```
typedef struct{char n;float x;float y;}Ponto;
void troca_nomes(Ponto *a, Ponto *b){
    char aux;
    aux = *a.n;
    *a.n = *b.n;
    *b.n = aux; 
}
int main(void){
    Ponto a = {'A', 1.5, 2.7};
    Ponto b = {'B', 3.9, 4.2};
    troca_nomes(&a,&b);
    printf("{%c,%.1f,%.1f}\n",a.n,a.x,a.y);
    printf("{%c,%.1f,%.1f}\n",b.n,b.x,b.y);
}
```

Comment: Como assim " troca somente dos caracteres a por b" ? Não ficou muito claro o que precisa de fazer, assim como qual o erro está a enfrentar.

Comment: o resulado do printf deve ser                                                                      {'B', 1.5, 2.7}                                                                                                        {'A', 3.9, 4.2}

Answer (score 1):

`*a.n` está errado. Com isso você está tentando acessar o valor da posição do ponteiro `n` dentro da estrutura `a`. Mas `n` não é um ponteiro, `a` é o ponteiro.

Teria que ser `(*a).n` ou `a->n`

Comment: Resolvido! Muito obrigado!